# <vlc> How to play a MPEG-4 from memory?

Tags: vlc

I have to play a MPEG-4 from memory, not file.

Because I only get a MPEG-4 file from streaming server and have to display it immediately.

I guess that I should use libvlc_media_new_path and libvlc_media_player_play, but the functions need a file in order to play.

Please helpl me~! :->

Comment: Please include some code to show
[what you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I am trying to analyze and design so I don't have any source code. I want to know how to use vlc in order to play MPEG-4 inmemory. Thank you for your reply :)

Answer (score 1):

May be you cay try [imem module](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=93842#p311611), which can fetch data from memory.

Some [sample code](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=94808) that posted from VLC forum.